# Getting this error xhr.js:258 POST http://localhost:3000/api/upload4 while using vue-media-upload in Nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

I am using vue-media-upload in Nuxt3 like this

```
    <Uploader
          :max="8"
          @max="console.log('max reached')"
          :maxFilesize="32"
          :warnings="false"
          :server="server"
          @change="console.log('changed')"
        />
```

I keep getting this error

```
xhr.js:258 POST http://localhost:3000/api/upload4
```

I am also using nuxt-security module.
Here is my Nuxt config

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: false },
  modules: [
    "@vueuse/nuxt",
    "@nuxt/image",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss",
    "nuxt-swiper",
    "@vee-validate/nuxt",
    "nuxt-security",
  ],

  security: {
    headers: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        "img-src": ["*", "data:"], // Allow images from any source
      },
    },
    corsHandler: {
      origin: "*",
    },
  },
  // image: { dir: "public/images/images" },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      googleMapsApiKey: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
      serverUrl: process.env.SERVER_URL,
    },
  },
});
```

Please help so that I can upload images using vue-media-upload.